# Question about supremum(inequality)

Tags: calculus

I am reading a proof and in one part there is:

> $\sup(f+g)\le \sup f +\sup g $

where $f$ and $g$ are functions. Why is this true?I can't see why(even though it might be obvious)

Comment: @GitGud I see, maybe few information that preceeded this might be important, so let me add it(is it no longer important that you deleted your comment?)

Comment: I removed my comment. The claim is correct. It might need an additional hypothesis depending on context. Do you want to consider stuff that looks like $+\infty \leq +\infty +\infty$?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, it is indeed defined on same closed interval$<a,b>$ it is one "ministep" in proof of linearity of Riemann integral. And no to the second question(so far if I get it, then we consider bounded functions when studying Riemann integrals.

Comment: Do you have continuity also? I'm asking this because of stuff like $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $\sup(f)$ is $+\infty$. For Riemann integrability you need the functions to be bounded.

Comment: I am not sure, in the theorem that is being proved we assume $f,g$ have Riemann integral on $<a,b>$

Comment: Then it is implicit that they are bounded because R-integrability requires it, therefore $\sup(f), \sup(g)$ and $\sup(f+g)$ are all real numbers. So you with to prove that $\sup(f+g)\leq \sup(f)+\sup(g)$. If you prove that $\sup(f)+\sup(g)$ is an upper bound of $\{f(x)+g(x)\colon x\in [a,b]\}$, then necessarily $\sup(f+g)\leq \sup(f)+\sup(g)$. Do you see why? Can you prove that $\sup(f)+\sup(g)$ is an upper bound of $\{f(x)+g(x)\colon x\in [a,b]\}$?

Comment: thank you for your help, Surb gave me full answer so I think I understand it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f,g$ have same respective domains $D_f,D_g$. By definition of the supremum, for every $x \in D_f \cap D_g$ it holds
$$ g(x) \leq \sup_{y \in D_g}g(y),$$
and thus
$$f(x)+g(x) \leq f(x)+\sup_{y \in D_g} g(y).$$
Since this is true for every $x \in D_f \cap D_g$ we may take the supremum over $x$ on both sides of the inequality to get 
$$\sup_{x \in D_f \cap D_g}(f(x)+g(x)) \leq \sup_{x \in D_f \cap D_g}f(x)+\sup_{y \in D_g} g(y)\leq \sup_{z \in D_f}f(z)+\sup_{y \in D_g} g(y).$$
Where we have used that $\sup_{x \in D_f \cap D_g}f(x) \leq \sup_{z \in D_f}f(z)$ since $D_f \cap D_g \subset D_f$.

Comment: Sorry to react so slowly, I am very slow thinker. Thanks for detailed answer, it is quite clear to me now.