# Which one is correct? (CSIR June'13)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\} , \{b_n\}$ be bounded sequences of positive numbers. Suppose if $\{a_n\}$ is increasing to $a$ ,then which one is true ?
>
> $$\sup_{n\ge1}a_n b_n=a\left(\sup_{n\ge1}b_n\right), \quad \text{ or } \quad \sup_{n\ge1}a_n b_n<a\left(\sup_{n\ge1}b_n\right)$$
>
> I think that second option is false if we take the $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is false either; take $(1/2,1,1,1,1,1,\dots)$ for $\{a_n\}$ and $(1,1/2,1/2,1/2,\dots)$ for $\{b_n\}$.

Comment: $a_n$ is not increasing in your example!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal Easy to modify! (Since you like !s...)

Comment: Yes it is. In is not strictly increasing, but it is increasing. You should possibly learn the definitions. If you however nead a strictly increasing $a_n$, subtract $1/(100n)$ from mine.

Comment: If $b_n$ is decreasing and converging to $b$ and we don't know about nature of $a_n$ then does $(\inf_{n\ge1}(a_n b_n))=(\inf_{n\ge 1}a_n)b$?

Comment: No, this is false either. It would be a useful exercise for you to construct a counterexample yourself;)

Comment: @Vladimir If suppose increasing means strictly increasing and decreasing means strictly decreasing will then equality holds in both cases?

Comment: No it will not. My examples can be modified as I explained already to refute the claim for the case of strictly increasing or decreasing sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Both are wrong in general, but both may occur (I tried to reuse your idea of $1-1/n$):

- For $n \geq 1$, let $b_n = a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$, then $$\sup_{n \geq 1} a_nb_n = 1 = \underbrace{\left(\sup_{n \geq 1} a_n\right)}_{=1} \underbrace{\left( \sup_{m \geq 1} b_m\right)}_{=1}$$
- for $n \geq 1$, let $a_n = 1- \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$, then 
  $$ \sup_{n \geq 1} a_nb_n = 1 < 2 = \underbrace{\left(\sup_{n \geq 1} a_n\right)}_{=1}\underbrace{\left( \sup_{m \geq 1} b_m\right)}_{=2}$$

In fact, in general
$$\sup_{n\geq 1} a_nb_n \leq \left(\sup_{n \geq 1} a_n\right)\left(\sup_{m \geq 1} b_m\right),$$
Note that this is always true, regardless of the properties of $\{a_n\},\{b_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842929/question-about-supremuminequality/842938#842938 you will find the same kind of relation but for functions.